# Probability of chosing at least two given letters out of three in sequence of five.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am self studying elementary Probability Theory, and I am not sure on how to solve this exercise, taken from the book *Understanding Probability* by Henk Tijms.

> For the upcoming drawing of the Bingo Lottery, five extra prizes have
>   been added to the pot. Each prize consists of an all-expenses paid
>   vacation trip. Each prize winner may choose from among three possible
>   destinations $A$, $B$ and $C$. The three destinations are equally
>   popular. The prize winners choose their destination indipendently of
>   each other. Calculate the probabilty that at least one of the
>   destinations $A$ and $B$ will be chosen. Also, calculate the
>   probability that not each of the three destinations will be chosen.

Regarding the first question, at first I thought that the probability that at least one of the destinations $A$ and $B$ is chosen should be the complementary probability that all the five winners choose the destination $C$, so:
$$P(A\cup B)=1-P(C)=1-1/3^5=\frac{242}{243}.$$
I would like to compute the same probability through the inclusion-exclusion rule,
$$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).$$
In this case it should be $P(A)=P(B)$, and to compute $P(A)$ I consider first the sequences of five letters containing exactly one time the letter $A$, which are  $\binom{5}{1}$ and have probability $\frac13 (\frac23)^4$.
Similarly, the sequences of five letters containing exactly two $A$s are $\binom{5}{2}$ and have probability $(\frac13)^2(\frac23)^3$. In this way, I get
$$P(A)=\sum_{k=1}^5 \binom{5}{k}\left(\frac13\right)^k\left(\frac23\right)^{5-k}.$$

To compute the probability that both the destinations $A$ and $B$ are chosen, I start by computing the probability that $A$ and $B$ are chosen one time each, and the remaining three winners choose $C$. In this case we have $\binom{5}{2}$ ways of forming the string $ABCCC$, which has probability $1/3^5$. Next, consider the two sequences $AABCC$ and $ABBCC$. The number of sequences are $2\cdot\binom{5}{3}$ and the probability is again $1/3^5$.
Summing up, I have
$$P(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{3^5}\sum_{k=2}^5 \binom{5}{k}(k-1).$$

However, when I compute the numerical values for $P(A\cup B)$, I get a number greater than one so I should be making a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your calculation of $P(A\cap B)$, it appears you're missing some cases.

Here's one way to organize the count . . .
$$
\begin{array}
{|c|c|c|c|} 
A&B&C&\text{count}&\text{times}\\ \hline
1&4&0&{\large{\binom{5}{1}}}{\large{\binom{4}{4}}}=5&2\\
2&3&0&{\large{\binom{5}{2}}}{\large{\binom{3}{3}}}=10&2\\ \hline
1&3&1&{\large{\binom{5}{1}}}{\large{\binom{4}{3}}}{\large{\binom{1}{1}}}=20&2\\
2&2&1&{\large{\binom{5}{2}}}{\large{\binom{3}{2}}}{\large{\binom{1}{1}}}=30&1\\ \hline
1&2&2&{\large{\binom{5}{1}}}{\large{\binom{4}{2}}}{\large{\binom{2}{2}}}=30&2\\ \hline
1&1&3&{\large{\binom{5}{1}}}{\large{\binom{4}{1}}}{\large{\binom{3}{3}}}=20&1\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
The entries in the "times" column are symmetry correction factors. For example, the count for the triple $(A,B,C)=(1,4,0)$ needs to be multiplied by $2$, so as to include the count for the symmetrically equivalent triple $(A,B,C)=(4,1,0)$.

Thus, the total count is
$$(5)(2)+(10)(2)+(20)(2)+(30)(1)+(30)(2)+(20)(1) =180$$
hence 
$$P(A\cap B) = \frac{180}{3^5} = \frac{20}{27}$$
so then
\begin{align*}
P(A\cup B) &=P(A)+P(B) - P(A\cap B)\\[6pt]
&=2\left(\frac{211}{3^5}\right)- \frac{20}{27}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{242}{243}
\end{align*}
as expected.

For the second problem, first find the probability that all $3$ destinations are chosen.

As shown in the table below, there are only two cases . . .
$$
\begin{array}
{|c|c|c|c|} 
A&B&C&\text{count}&\text{times}\\ \hline
1&1&3&{\large{\binom{5}{1}}}{\large{\binom{4}{1}}}{\large{\binom{3}{3}}}=20&3\\ \hline
1&2&2&{\large{\binom{5}{1}}}{\large{\binom{4}{2}}}{\large{\binom{2}{2}}}=30&3\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
Thus, the total count is
$$(20)(3)+(30)(3)=150$$
hence 
$$P(A\cap B \cap C) = \frac{150}{3^5} = \frac{50}{81}$$
so the probability that *not* all $3$ destinations are chosen is
$$1- \frac{50}{81} = \frac{31}{81}$$